# Why is rendered playback slower than my project?

Tags: vegas-pro

I have a project that's 1280X720 @25

I do have clips in the project that are various resolutions, but this hasnt seem to be a problem.

I render as the "Match the Project Settings" and everytime the video plays back much slower.

How to fix?!
Also sometimes my project becomes off time. But if I restart Vegas it fixes itself.

Comment: How much slower is much slower?  What do you mean by your project becoming off time?

Comment: Do you mean the video renders slower than the preview in the editor or do you mean the final rendered video plays back more slowly than the preview in the editor?

Comment: What and how did you set the "project properties" ?

Answer (score 3):

This was resolved due to incorrect audio sample rate with my DAW. In Vegas I was editing in 24 bit 48,000Hz. After render, my systems was attempting to playback the video file at 16bit 41,000Hz which will cause this effect.